# Flexbox not containing elements the way it should

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox for my webpage's responsiveness and the positioning of my elements, but for some reason I cannot get the containers text to stay within the box. [image]

My goal is to have all of the text in their designated divs, but it continues to overflow into the page. What am I doing wrong here?

html

```
 <div class='boxes-top'>
        <div class='box-1'>
            <h4>The Historical Carousel</h4>
            <p>Perfect for private parties or an impromptu ride,
                this historic icon pairs perfectly with treats from the vintage
                soda-fountain located inside.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 394-8042</p>
        </div>
        <div class='box-2'>
            <h4>Playland Arcade</h4>
            <p>For kids and kids at heart, this classic arcade will 
                indulge all your nostalgia and test all your skills. 
                Skeeball is only the beginning.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 451-5133</p>
        </div>
        <div class='box-3'>
            <h4>Santa Monica Pier Aquarium</h4>
            <p>The hidden gem of the Pier, Heal the Bay’s public marine-education 
                 center is hands-on fun tucked just underneath the historic Carousel building.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 393-6149</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='boxes-bottom'> 
        <div class='box-1'>
            <h4>Marlene's Beach Comber</h4>
            <p>This is your one-stop beach shop for sunscreen, towels, beach mats and more. 
                If the Beachcomber doesn’t have it, it may not exist.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 260-8744</p>
        </div>
        <div class='box-2'>
            <h4>Pier Bait and Tackle</h4>
            <p>Yes, you can fish at the Pier! And whether you’re a regular or want to try your 
                 hand at this relaxing past-time for the day, the Bait & Tackle shop has your needs covered.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 576-2014</p>
        </div>
        <div class='box-3'>
            <h4>Live music & dancing at Rusty's</h4>
            <p>When the sun dips on your day at the beach, stay for some all-American live rock and drink 
                specials at Rusty's.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 393-7437</p> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.boxes-top{
    display: flex;
} 

.boxes-top div{
    padding: 10px;
}

.boxes-bottom{
    display: flex;
} 

.boxes-bottom div{
    padding: 10px;
}

.box-1 {
    flex: 1;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.box-2 {
    flex: 1;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: teal;
}

.box-3 {
    flex: 1;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the height for your boxes to read auto instead of 150px. If you set a dimension for the boxes you are only restricting the box to be 150px rather than the content within the box. With auto, the boxes will be forced to fit the contents in the box. Hope this helps you.

```css
.box-1 {
  flex: 1;
  height: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box-2 {
  flex: 1;
  height: auto;
  background-color: teal;
}

.box-3 {
  flex: 1;
  height: auto;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your boxes have nowhere to expand (which is the core concept of `flex`. Instead of a fixed `height`, you'll likely instead want to make use of `min-height`. This allows them to expand as needed, while also retaining a `height` of *at least* `150px`:

```css
.boxes-top {
  display: flex;
}

.boxes-top div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.boxes-bottom {
  display: flex;
}

.boxes-bottom div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.box-1 {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box-2 {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: teal;
}

.box-3 {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class='boxes-top'>
  <div class='box-1'>
    <h4>The Historical Carousel</h4>
    <p>Perfect for private parties or an impromptu ride, this historic icon pairs perfectly with treats from the vintage soda-fountain located inside.</p>
    <p>Phone: (310) 394-8042</p>
  </div>
  <div class='box-2'>
    <h4>Playland Arcade</h4>
    <p>For kids and kids at heart, this classic arcade will indulge all your nostalgia and test all your skills. Skeeball is only the beginning.</p>
    <p>Phone: (310) 451-5133</p>
  </div>
  <div class='box-3'>
    <h4>Santa Monica Pier Aquarium</h4>
    <p>The hidden gem of the Pier, Heal the Bay’s public marine-education center is hands-on fun tucked just underneath the historic Carousel building.</p>
    <p>Phone: (310) 393-6149</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='boxes-bottom'>
  <div class='box-1'>
    <h4>Marlene's Beach Comber</h4>
    <p>This is your one-stop beach shop for sunscreen, towels, beach mats and more. If the Beachcomber doesn’t have it, it may not exist.</p>
    <p>Phone: (310) 260-8744</p>
  </div>
  <div class='box-2'>
    <h4>Pier Bait and Tackle</h4>
    <p>Yes, you can fish at the Pier! And whether you’re a regular or want to try your hand at this relaxing past-time for the day, the Bait & Tackle shop has your needs covered.</p>
    <p>Phone: (310) 576-2014</p>
  </div>
  <div class='box-3'>
    <h4>Live music & dancing at Rusty's</h4>
    <p>When the sun dips on your day at the beach, stay for some all-American live rock and drink specials at Rusty's.</p>
    <p>Phone: (310) 393-7437</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fixed height from the boxes. You can also simplify your CSS by giving common elements the same class name:

```css
.boxes {display: flex}
.box{flex: 1; padding: 10px}
.box-1 {background-color: yellow}
.box-2 {background-color: teal}
.box-3 {background-color: grey}
```

```html
<div class='boxes boxes-top'>
  <div class='box box-1'>
    <h4>The Historical Carousel</h4>
    <p>Perfect for private parties or an impromptu ride, this historic icon pairs perfectly with treats from the vintage soda-fountain located inside.</p>
    <p>Phone: (310) 394-8042</p>
  </div>
  <div class='box box-2'>
    <h4>Playland Arcade</h4>
    <p>For kids and kids at heart, this classic arcade will indulge all your nostalgia and test all your skills. Skeeball is only the beginning.</p>
    <p>Phone: (310) 451-5133</p>
  </div>
  <div class='box box-3'>
    <h4>Santa Monica Pier Aquarium</h4>
    <p>The hidden gem of the Pier, Heal the Bay’s public marine-education center is hands-on fun tucked just underneath the historic Carousel building.</p>
    <p>Phone: (310) 393-6149</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='boxes boxes-bottom'>
  <div class='box box-1'>
    <h4>Marlene's Beach Comber</h4>
    <p>This is your one-stop beach shop for sunscreen, towels, beach mats and more. If the Beachcomber doesn’t have it, it may not exist.</p>
    <p>Phone: (310) 260-8744</p>
  </div>
  <div class='box box-2'>
    <h4>Pier Bait and Tackle</h4>
    <p>Yes, you can fish at the Pier! And whether you’re a regular or want to try your hand at this relaxing past-time for the day, the Bait & Tackle shop has your needs covered.</p>
    <p>Phone: (310) 576-2014</p>
  </div>
  <div class='box box-3'>
    <h4>Live music & dancing at Rusty's</h4>
    <p>When the sun dips on your day at the beach, stay for some all-American live rock and drink specials at Rusty's.</p>
    <p>Phone: (310) 393-7437</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your height from your boxes.

```css
.boxes-top{
    display: flex;
    margin: 1px;
} 

.boxes-top div{
    padding: 10px;
}

.boxes-bottom{
    display: flex;
    margin: 1px;
} 

.boxes-bottom div{
    padding: 10px;
}

.box-1 {
    flex: 1; 
    background-color: yellow;
}

.box-2 {
    flex: 1; 
    background-color: teal;
}

.box-3 {
    flex: 1; 
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class='boxes-top'>
        <div class='box-1'>
            <h4>The Historical Carousel</h4>
            <p>Perfect for private parties or an impromptu ride,
                this historic icon pairs perfectly with treats from the vintage
                soda-fountain located inside.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 394-8042</p>
        </div>
        <div class='box-2'>
            <h4>Playland Arcade</h4>
            <p>For kids and kids at heart, this classic arcade will 
                indulge all your nostalgia and test all your skills. 
                Skeeball is only the beginning.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 451-5133</p>
        </div>
        <div class='box-3'>
            <h4>Santa Monica Pier Aquarium</h4>
            <p>The hidden gem of the Pier, Heal the Bay’s public marine-education 
                 center is hands-on fun tucked just underneath the historic Carousel building.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 393-6149</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='boxes-bottom'> 
        <div class='box-1'>
            <h4>Marlene's Beach Comber</h4>
            <p>This is your one-stop beach shop for sunscreen, towels, beach mats and more. 
                If the Beachcomber doesn’t have it, it may not exist.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 260-8744</p>
        </div>
        <div class='box-2'>
            <h4>Pier Bait and Tackle</h4>
            <p>Yes, you can fish at the Pier! And whether you’re a regular or want to try your 
                 hand at this relaxing past-time for the day, the Bait & Tackle shop has your needs covered.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 576-2014</p>
        </div>
        <div class='box-3'>
            <h4>Live music & dancing at Rusty's</h4>
            <p>When the sun dips on your day at the beach, stay for some all-American live rock and drink 
                specials at Rusty's.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 393-7437</p> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

If your all boxes are same and want to make fixed responsive boxes.
then need to add one parent wrapper instead of breaking in two parts.

```css
.boxes-top{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
} 
.boxes{ 
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: darkcyan;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='boxes-top'>
        <div class='boxes box-1'>
            <h4>The Historical Carousel</h4>
            <p>Perfect for private parties or an impromptu ride,
                this historic icon pairs perfectly with treats from the vintage
                soda-fountain located inside.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 394-8042</p>
        </div>
        <div class='boxes box-2'>
            <h4>Playland Arcade</h4>
            <p>For kids and kids at heart, this classic arcade will 
                indulge all your nostalgia and test all your skills. 
                Skeeball is only the beginning.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 451-5133</p>
        </div>
        <div class='boxes box-3'>
            <h4>Santa Monica Pier Aquarium</h4>
            <p>The hidden gem of the Pier, Heal the Bay’s public marine-education 
                 center is hands-on fun tucked just underneath the historic Carousel building.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 393-6149</p>
        </div>
        <div class='boxes box-4'>
            <h4>Marlene's Beach Comber</h4>
            <p>This is your one-stop beach shop for sunscreen, towels, beach mats and more. 
                If the Beachcomber doesn’t have it, it may not exist.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 260-8744</p>
        </div>
        <div class='boxes box-5'>
            <h4>Pier Bait and Tackle</h4>
            <p>Yes, you can fish at the Pier! And whether you’re a regular or want to try your 
                 hand at this relaxing past-time for the day, the Bait & Tackle shop has your needs covered.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 576-2014</p>
        </div>
        <div class='boxes box-6'>
            <h4>Live music & dancing at Rusty's</h4>
            <p>When the sun dips on your day at the beach, stay for some all-American live rock and drink 
                specials at Rusty's.</p>
            <p>Phone: (310) 393-7437</p> 
        </div>
    </div>
```